# High memory pressure on M1 MacBook Pro running Monterey 12.1, possible memory leak?

Tags: mac, xcode, memory, monterey, memory-leak

I remember in the first few months the memory pressure never hits red.
the lldb started spiking to 2GB+ after I left the mac on sleep while Xcode was open, could that be the reason?

Stutters happen sometimes while Xcode, Chrome, and Figma running.
[image: Memory usage while running Xcode & Figma]

Comment: As you can see, Figma is using up more than half of your memory. Just quit and restart the app, and report the issue to Figma.

Comment: I am not surprised it stutters. You are pushing it a bit for an 8GB MBP - Xcode and Chrome use lots of RAM as well as, you have found, Figma.  Over 5GB of swap and lots of compressed are warning signs. Try running less memory hungry apps at once.  You could try stopping and restarting Xcode, too.

Comment: I see, so it's not a memory leak then. So running one big app is the limit for 8GB MBP.
 I'll try switching to Safari or Edge, see if it helps too.

Comment: I don't know anything about Figma (ask the developer if it might be a memory leak), but Xcode and Chrome are well known for high memory usage. Just exit those apps you are not actively using.